# Is there any way to use Javascript to do a Ctrl-F5 refresh?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a small asp file that runs inside of a frame. Is there any way that i can do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> type of refresh and reload the whole browser window. I've tried `parent.location.reload(true)`, `location.reload()`, and quite a few others. The page doesnt seem to want to redirect. If i do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on my keyboard it reloads fine. Any help is much appreciated

also i need to refresh/update my .js files in the browser through <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: You're solving your issue in a wrong way. And better you describe **why** you need that, because there is a better solution (assuming your current attempt is a "solution", even though it is not)

Comment: You've got a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following, FIrst of all in your `<head>` tag put following two lines

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

and then You can use `location.reload(true)`

Comment: greattt! hehe.... the expiration is the key before reloading....

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice example placed here: http://grizzlyweb.com/webmaster/javascripts/refresh.asp

Have fun!