# Automatically refresh Google Apps Script after set period of time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, meta, page-refresh

I'm working on a portal which has a set of forms that can be accessed from the main screen and then a page which has reporting based on a users submissions to said forms.

The forms write to a singular Google spreadsheet where data is manipulated and a "Status" is thrown out.

I have got this status, among other data onto my reporting screen and at the minute it is static until the users physically refreshes the page.

I am wanting to make it so that this report refreshes automatically, say every 60 seconds, so any changes are reflected to the user.

I've spent time researching, and have managed to get two options which seem to be in the beginning stages of working, but I am unable to work out how to solve the issues I'm still having.

One choice was to do a meta refresh. The code for this is:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=HereIsTheURL"/>
```

This version works, but only in the first instance. i.e the page successfully reloads the first time, but when the second instance comes around all I get is a blank white screen.

The second choice I have been using is with JS. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function () { 
  location.reload();
 }, 60000);
</script>
```

However, this simply returns a blank white screen every time.

Further information:

I am using HTMLService in Apps Script.
The page on which the Log/report appears has the full script URL + "?page=pagename"

Does anybody have any ideas how to change the code so that the page refreshes properly every time?

Updated below with HTML content:

```
 <div id="content" >
  <h1>Change Log:</h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
 <table id = "user" style="width:100%" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <thead>
               <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Change Request Date</th>
                <th>Change Request</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Completed By</th>
                <th>Date Completed</th>
              </tr>

 </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr> 

         </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the following cache settings in combination with location.reload(true)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633374/is-there-any-way-to-use-javascript-to-do-a-ctrl-f5-refresh

Comment: setTimeout executes you code once at 60 seconds whereas using setInterval will execute your code every 60seconds

Comment: Ted - I've just implemented that, alongside changing setTimeout to setInterval and my problem is still there. All I get is a blank white screen

Comment: You may have to write the HTML which create dashboard on to a javascript function and call that  function every 60 second with setTimeout(). This should be fairly easy since you have already wrote working HTML.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't use location.reload because of redirecting security issues (wild guess), but you could reset the whole page, with setTimeouts in the Javascript HTML, and update the page, if you'd share you HTML code we could help on how to update them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking it could be to do with security too as it's in apps script as opposed to other consoles. For info, I've added the HTML to the question

Comment: I've needed to see the javascript functions, but probably you'll just remove the added elementes and re-run the functions, really simple.